# SQL Server Replications missing from Local Publications, still present in Replication Monitor and Distribution database

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, database-replication, snapshot

Upon trying to investigate and adapt the publication of a snapshot replication, I found that the Replication folder "Local Publications" contained no publications.

[image: Screenshot of the SQL Server Instance, the replication folder showing no publications]

The SQL Server in question is SQL Server 2014 with Service Pack 3 and Cumulative Update 4.
It is a 64-bit Enterprise edition.

Despite the Local Publication folder containing no publications, the three publications are displayed in the Replication Monitor. I can see the publications and the articles with the following T-SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
  msp.publication AS PublicationName,
  msa.publisher_db AS DatabaseName,
  msa.article AS ArticleName,
  msa.source_owner AS SchemaName,
  msa.source_object AS TableName
FROM distribution.dbo.MSarticles msa
JOIN distribution.dbo.MSpublications msp ON msa.publication_id = msp.publication_id
ORDER BY 
  msp.publication, 
  msa.article
```

The three replications are all snapshot replications.

Why did they disappear?
How can I restore them?

Comment: There is a lot of metadata involved in replication and it need not always agree with each other if a problem occurs -- that and name mismatches can trip you up. First verify that `@@SERVERNAME` is what SSMS thinks it is; SSMS has hangups about managing replication when accessing the server through an alias (it normally gives an error, but sometimes it just silently fails). If that's all fine, you can launch a profiler from SSMS to trace the statements SSMS *itself* issues to get the replication data, for debugging purposes, to see where the mismatch happens.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the Profiler to investigate further and try to start it via the Replication monitor. Though I did notice that the folder which should contain the snapshot remains empty (I had hopes to find indications of what happened in there).

The '@@Servername' statement indicates that the SSMS and server data aligns. It is the same displayed in the overall overview and in the Replication Monitor.